# Is there an efficient way, besides using a double for loop, to generate a LIST of all possible pairs of indices (i, j) given an array so that i <= j?

Tags: javascript, arrays, data-structures

Just to note - I don't just want the number of all the possible pairs, I need an actual array/list of all possible indices pairs.

I get that you can use a double for loop or generate combinations but the problem is that the time complexity would be O(N^2) and O(k(N! / [(N-k)! * k!])) where k = 2, respectively. So it makes it difficult to generate all possible pairs of indices if you have a large array of say over 1000 elements.

For example, the following worked when I use small arrays but is there anything more efficient to generate this list of [i, j] indices or an algorithm anyone could point me towards that might give me a solution?

Double for loop:

```
let pairs = [];
for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  for (let j = i; j < array.length; j++) {
    pairs.push([i, j]);
  }
}
```

Combinations using backtracking:

```
function findPairs(arr) {
    let result = [];
    backtrack(0, result, arr.length, [], 2);

    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        result.push([i, i]);
    }

    return result;
}

function backtrack(start, result, len, curr, k = 2) {
    if (curr.length === k) result.push([...curr]);

    for (let i = start; i < len + 1; i++) {
        curr.push(i);
        backtrack(i + 1, result, len, curr, 2);
        curr.pop()
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: No, if the resulting structure has X elements, no matter your algorithm, it will have to perform the most nested operation at least X times - no way around that

Comment: Think about it... if the list to generate contains `I * J` elements... how are you going to generate it in less time than `O(I*J)`???

Comment: Answering the question in the title: You can use a single loop with some arithmetic, but you'll get the same complexity.

Comment: No harm no foul in trying to make it better but I think you're overthinking it. It's just a double loop, continue with your main goal instead of focusing in a minor efficiency tweak.

Comment: Depending on the use case, you might be able to have less than Q(n*n) if you sort the array based on some criteria, and then in your nested look look only at items > current index.

Comment: Depending on how the indices are used, you might use a generator instead of pre-calculating the indices. That way, index generation can be spread out over the other operations involving the indices (it will have an O(1) amortized cost for operations that are O(n*n)), and can be combined with other generators. There will be a time-space tradeoff; if the same indices are used in multiple places (i.e. the generator is called multiple times), each will spend time generating the sequence anew.

Comment: Thank you to especially @outis - very helpful and insightful comment.

Comment: Note that "O(k(N! / [(N-k)! * k!])) where k = 2" is `O(N²)`.